# prooftrees.sty - why are line numbers overlapping and how to avoid?

Tags: forest, trees, logic, prooftrees

Why are the "6" and "7" overlapping here and how can I avoid it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}{}
[A
    [A
        [A
            [A
                [A
                    [A
                        [A]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [A
        [A
            [A
                [A]
                [A]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I'm aware of the "move by" option, however in a large, complex tree this adds a lot of sometimes quite long single branches which doesn't look very good imo. It seems to me that when a branching rule is applied, the branches should either increase/decrease in size so that this doesn't happen.

Edit - something like this is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Good to see you've provided a minimal working example, that is very helpful. It is however not fully clear (to me) how you would want the output to look, and how automated this should be. Do you want the branching step (7) below the last single row (8 in this case). i.e., extending the edges? Or do you want it to be positioned between 6 and 7 as it is now, with extra space within the single branch? Or maybe something like pushing the 7 a bit to the left and keep the other numbers as they are?

Comment: Did you try it with `\begin{prooftree}{single branches=true}` ?  Is that output acceptable?

Comment: Pages 22-23 of the manual (try `texdoc prooftrees`) suggests that *automatically* fixing issues like this is not always possible...

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your reply. I would either like the branching step (7) extended like you said or preferably I would like it aligned with either 6 or 8. I know the latter would produce the "merge delimiter" / "Merging conflicting justifications" warning, but I don't really mind having multiple justifications on the same line. The problem is I don't know how to tell prooftrees to align it with either 6 or 8.

Comment: @Thruston Thank you for your reply. I have tried constructing trees with `\begin{prooftree}{single branches=true}` however this doesn't necessarily fix it. Well that might explain a lot as I have fiddled around with the "move by" along with the "single branches" option quite a bit, and still struggled to to avoid these issues. I *can* do it, it just ends up adding lots of long single branches, which I don't really want.

Comment: @Marijn the problem with extending the branches with the "move by" option is that it often tries to skip multiple lines even when I put `move by=1` and so creates large branches which I don't really want

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: If you don't want to move things manually, it needs to align with line 5 and that is, in my opinion, what `prooftrees` should do in this case.

Comment: I've just created a modified version of `prooftrees` which will do this. However, since it will not do what you've actually said you want, I'm not sure what use it may be. However, I will probably have the next version do this. It shouldn't generate overlapping nodes by default. So I will try to stop it reducing the distance between the single-branch lines in the relevant cases. That is, if there is a next version. I don't know how much use it is.

Answer (score 3):

> **Update**
>
> Version 0.7 of `prooftrees` now produces
>
> [image: The fifth line in the left branch aligned with disjunctions on the fifth line of the right branch aligned, all on line 5, so the final node from the left branch is on line 7.]
>
> given just
>
> ```
> \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
> \usepackage{prooftrees}
> \begin{document}
> \begin{prooftree}{}
> [A
>     [A
>         [A
>             [A
>                 [A
>                   [A
>                         [A]
>                     ]
>                 ]
>             ]
>         ]
>     ]
>     [A
>         [A
>         [A
>                 [A]
>                 [A]
>             ]
>         ]
>     ]
> ]
> \end{prooftree}
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> That is, the overlapping nodes (which I considered a bug) is now
>   hopefully fixed.

---

**Original answer**

`prooftrees` should not generate this output by default. That is, I consider it a bug. However, it is unlikely to generate precisely the output you want by default either. That I do not consider a bug.

With current `prooftrees`, I suggest

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}{}
  [A
    [A
        [A
            [A
                [A
                  [A
                        [A]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [A
        [A
            [A
                [A, move by=1]
                [A, move by=1]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: suggested tableau]

Alternatively,

```
\begin{prooftree}{}
  [A
      [A
          [A
              [A
                [A, move by=1, edge+={draw=none}% if you don't want an edge
                    [A
                          [A]
                      ]
                  ]
              ]
          ]
      ]
      [A
          [A
              [A
                  [A]
                  [A]
              ]
          ]
      ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
```

[image: alternative tableau]

Comment: I didn't answer the 'why?' The answer is that when proof line numbers are assigned, the disjunctions on the right have a smaller `y` than the non-disjunction on the left, because the one on the left has `l` set to `\baselineskip`, whereas the ones on the right don't. This avoids overly leggy trees. So the disjunctions get a new line number, because `y` is less than it is for the non-disjunction, but the `l` on the right is not twice `\baselineskip`, so the next number on the left gets another number which overlaps with it. The disjunction should be on line 5.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Not sure if you've released the updated version or not, but if you have I'll definitely give it a try, otherwise the second solution looks quite elegant too.

Comment: @BenLoewe I haven't published it yet. If you are prepared to try it, send me an email and I'll send you a copy to test. That way, you can drop it in your working directory and just delete it if things go wrong. And you can let me know if it works OK or you find problems.

Comment: Yeah I'll give it a try, I'm a LaTeX newbie so I don't how well I'll be able to diagnose any problems if they arise.

Comment: where can I find your email?

Comment: @BenLoewe It's in the `prooftrees` docs. In a footnote on the first page, I think.